# GNU Plot Giving error in OpenTSDB

Tags: gnuplot, opentsdb

I am new to OpenTSDB, I successfully installed OpenTSB with all its dependencies.
On plotting I am getting error in log file as:

```
Thu Jul 09 10:19:13 GMT-400 2015    WARN    Gnuplot #2  tsd.HttpQuery
[id: 0x4146b6a2, /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx => /xxx.x.xxx.xxx:xxxx] Bad Request on /q?start=2015/07/09-00:00:00&end=2015/07/09-10:20:27&m=sum:temperatures&o=&yrange=%5B0:%5D&wxh=1295x538&json: <pre>Gnuplot stderr:

set term png small size 1295,538
         ^
"/tmp/tsd/6ec53dbb.gnuplot", line 1: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list

</pre>
```

Some solutions for this problem mention that I should install x11 for Octava

```
sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11
```

This doesn't work for my case, I am using UBUNTU not mac.

Answer (score 0):

Plots are created using dynamic PNG images. To support PNG we need to have libgd2 package.

1. Please install libgd2 package
2. Restart gnuplot and openTSDB
3. Open http://localhost:4242/ and see if you still getting the error